# How to apply replacement on a string using regular expression dynamically JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, tags

I have this string and this regular expression. It matches hyperlinks FYI.

```
var str = "string https://www.pleasehelpme.com string";
var expr = "^(https:|http:|www\.)\S*";
var regex = new RegExp( expr  );
```

If I want to replace the Url by a constant string I should do this:

```
var myconstantstring = "https://www.thxforyourhelpcommunity.com"
var replaced = str.replace(regex, myconstantstring);
console.log(replaced);
// displays "string https://www.thxforyourhelpcommunity.com string"
```

But I want to replace the url in the string by the same url, surrounded by HTML tags so the result will be as follow:

```
"string <a href='https://www.thxforyourhelpcommunity.com'>clic here </a> string"
```

Is there a way to do it by getting the matchings table returned and replace it directly into the string? 
Obviously, I can acheive this by separating the process with multiple little steps but this is not what I'm looking for.

Thank you all.

Comment: Why not replace with `<a href='...'>click here</a>`?

Comment: Your regex is not defined correctly. Do you have `var expr = "^(https:|http:|www\\.)\\S*";`? Then, do you mean to replace the whole match with itself with tags added around the match?

Comment: You are right, that is exactly what I meant @wiktor Stribizew.

Comment: I thought you wanted `var replaced = str.replace(/(?:https?:|www\.)\S*/g, "<a href='$&'>Click here</a>");`.

Comment: I'm waiting for you to post your comment as an answer. Thats way I can accept it. Thank you very much.